# How to handle requestbody to set valid values from enum?

Tags: java, spring, enums, controller, request

I have DB with the fields name, last name and age. I have a separate enum class with name, e.g. "Alex", "Peter", "Duncan"

I have an API, that changes the name with payload from the request body

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/name", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public JsonView changeName(@Valid @RequestBody NameDTO nameDTO)
        throws Exception
    {
        _service.changename(getUser(),nameDTO.getName);
        return JsonView.EMPTY_VIEW;
    }
```

My ENUM class

```
public enum Name
{
    ALEX("alex")
    PETER("peter")
    DUNCAN("duncan")
}
```

My NameDTO class

```
public class NameDTO
{
    private String name;

    public NameDTO()
    {
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public NameDTO(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So I want to make some handler, if I will send in JSON in request body something different from my values from ENUM class to get 400 Error

JSON body

```
    {
       "name": "Alex"
    }
```

GOOD, db updates with this name

```
    {
       "name": "David"
    }
```

Should give 400 (now it gives 500)

Comment: `nameDTO.getName` is not valid syntax (unless the field is named 'getName', which it isn't)

Comment: Json_property is "name", handles with dto getName, what's wrong? Everything compiles OK

Comment: `_service.changename(getUser(),nameDTO.getName);` is not valid. It can't possibly compile. You either need parentheses `nameDTO.getName()` or for the field to be public and called `getName`.

Comment: I don't show service class, but it compiles well, I just want to know how to handle it from 500 to 400

Comment: Likewise, your enum doesn't compile because there are no commas separating the constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made something like this

I've created static enum list

```
private static final List<String> NAME = Arrays.asList(
        Name.ALEX.toString(),
        Name.PETER.toString(),
        Name.DUNCAN.toString();
```

And simple check in controller before executing service method

```
if (!Name.contains(nameDTO.getName)
{
throw new Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is, you want to store String representation of ENum value in database and if its a wrong value then it should throw error..

This should work,

```
public class NameDTO
{

    private Name name;

   @JsonDeserialize(using = NameDeSerializer.class)
   public void setName(Name name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }
```

}

```
@Component
public class NameDeSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<Name> {

@Override
public Name deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException {
    if (jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
        try {
            return Name.valueOf(jp.getText());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new CustomException(String.format("Invalid value for Name %s", jp.getText()));
        }
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public Class<Name> handledType() {
    return Name.class;
}
```

}

Exception handler to throw *400* status code

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class DefaultExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(value = { CustomException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomError(CustomExceptionex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = ex.getErrorMessage();
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, new FusionExceptionResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), bodyOfResponse),
                new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
}
```

So,

PUT /userID/name {
  "name" : "David"
}

First hit the *NameDeSerializer* and check for value. It will throw an *CustomException* exception at `try` block. Now, *DefaultExceptionHandler*  will handle *CustomException* and will throw *400* error code.